# Changing contrast of a text layer works as preview, but not after confirming

Tags: gimp

I'm using Gimp 2.10 and have the problem that a modification doesn't take effekt.

I created a text field (which is created automatically as a separate layer) with a specific text. Then I wanted to change the contrast of the text/layer.
In the contrast window I get the preview of how the "new" text will look like.
However when clicking on the "OK" button, the modification is withdrawn and the old text remains.

What could be the reason for that? And what could be done to get this issue fixed?

Comment: What version of Gimp is this? The Brightness/Contrast tool shows the preview on the canvas directly. In addition as created text layers are of a uniform color on a transparent background, so brightness/contrast won't change them much in most cases (unless you use midtone colors, but all you will see is a general luminosity shift...)

Comment: It is version 2.10 (I wrote it in my post above). The thing is the contrast changes significantly in the text during the preview, but why are the changes being rejected after pressing "OK" ?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot shwing the tools being used?

Comment: Seen complements to your question on gimp-forum.net, so you can cancel this question since what you are after is [very different from what you are asking](https://xyproblem.info/).